# How can use getCallingCode and getCountryCode methods of react-native-phone-number-input?

Tags: react-native

How can i use the methods `getCallingCode` and `getCountryCode` from [react-native-phone-number-input](https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input)  ? if i tried :

```
import { getCallingCode } from `react-native-phone-number-input`
 ...

     <PhoneInput
       onChangeFormattedText={(value) => {
        (isValidPhoneNumber(value)) ? this.updatePhone('phoneNumber', value) : value;
         console.log(value.getCallingCode());
        }
        }
        label="PHONE NUMBER:"
      />
```

i'm getting an error saying that `value.getCallingCode() is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way

```
const phoneInput = useRef<PhoneInput>(null);

<PhoneInput
            ref={phoneInput}
            .....
/>
```

More details [Here](https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input)

```
phoneInput.current?.getCallingCode();
```